# Can not change value of textsize in ListView in different fragment class

Tags: android-fragments, arraylist, android-listfragment, text-size

I want to change text size in `ListView` in different fragment class. I declared the variable in other class as

```
public static TextView title;
```

then I change the value of that textsize  by using class fragment.

```
title.setTextSize(30);
```

when I click
    back to other activity it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
public class Setting extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RadioGroup Text_Size;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setting);

        Text_Size = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup);
        Text_Size.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {

                switch (checkedId) {
                    case R.id.small:
                        HotNewsFrag.title.setTextSize(15);
                        break;
                    case R.id.medium:
                        HotNewsFrag.title.setTextSize(20);
                        break;
                    case R.id.big:
                        HotNewsFrag.title.setTextSize(30);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        LinearLayout back = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.back1);
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent setting = new Intent(Setting.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(setting);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my fragment:

```
public class HotNewsFrag extends Fragment {

    private View view;
    private ListView listOfNews;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<HotNews> arraylist1;
    public static String newsid;
    public static TextView title;
}
```

Comment: Please add the code for the Fragment as well. It will be easier to help

Comment: there're alot of code..it's difficult to post

Answer (score 0):

The way you are handling  this is completely wrong.

**BIG PROBLEM:**
defining the text View as Static would cause memory leak and prevent your view and activity from being garbage collected.

here are two approaches :

**FIRST : SHARED PREFERENCES AND ONRESUME**

you can store the text size in a sharedPreference and in your activity or fragments, you override onResume and set text size to our textsview again by the value in sharedPreference which you stored before

**SECOND : BROADCAST RECEIVERS**

You can use broadcast receivers and register them wherever you like. whenever the user change the text size, you send local broadcast and change text size wherever you register that.

```
Text_Size.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            int txtSize=0;
            switch (checkedId)
            {
                case R.id.small:
                    txtSize=15;
                    break;
                case R.id.medium:
                    txtSize=20;
                    break;
                case R.id.big:
                    txtSize=30;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
                Setting.this.getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED",0).edit().putInt("FONT_SIZE",txtSize).commit();
        }
    });
```

In your fragment

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    title.setTextSize(getActivity().getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED",0).getInt("FONT_SIZE",20));
    ADAPTER_OF_YOUR_LISTVIEW.notifyAll();
}
```

Comment: i try to use your opinion but it doesn't work i'm not sure i'm right or not..can you give me an exmple of code

Comment: You should notify the adapter about the changes
i edited my answer again @Boy

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the Text to become Emphasized, Try using `SetTypeFace.BOLD`